# Elliptic Filter Code

Tags: c++, c, filtering

I'm needing a elliptic filter code in c or c++, this code should filter a float input array.
Does anyone there have any code to do it?

Best

Comment: you can't ask for someone to code!

Comment: More specifically, this is offtopic since you're asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: Sorry for asking for code...

Comment: I need the most delicious tasting dessert ever created. Do you know how to make it?

Comment: Yes, I have code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use e.g. MATLAB to *design* your filter (using e.g. the [`ellip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/ellip.html) function), you can take the resulting filter coefficients and very easily implement the filter in software (it's just a matter of multiplying the float values by the coefficients and following the rational filter equation).

Comment: This answered my question. Sorry all for asking for code.